# How to store json object in PostgreSQL database using Play Framework and AngularJS/CoffeeScript?

Tags: angularjs, json, postgresql, playframework, coffeescript

Please let me know that how can I store my json object/document in PostgreSQL after clicking of my Submit button, here I am using Play Framework and AngularJS/CoffeeScript code.

Script:

```
(function() {
  var testValue;
  testValue = {};
  $('input[id=buttonId]').click(function() {
    var name;
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    testValue[name] = $(this).val();
  });
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $('input[id=fileId]').each(function($i) {
      var name;
      name = $(this).attr('name');
      testValue[name] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(testValue));//it gives the json object, after clicking Submit button
  });
})();
```

html:

```
<input type='button' value='button0' id="buttonId" class='button' name='testutton'/><br><br>
<input type='file' name='file' value='file upload' id="fileId"/><br><br>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' id='submit'>
```

Play Framework configurations for PostgreSQL:
app.conf:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testingdatabase"
db.default.user=tester
db.default.password=tester
```

build.scala:

```
"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"
```

Play server is resolved the required jdbc driver to connect to PostgreSQL database. Here I don't know that how can I proceed to my next step to connect with the database that to store my json object in database or how can I start my next steps to do this using Play server and AngularJS/CoffeeScript. Please help me regard this, as I am doing research, but couldn't get any solution.

Comment: Is your database set up? Do you have a Play app running? Do you have a controller set up to receive the request?

Comment: thanks for your reply, Steve Chaloner, Yes, I have installed Play Framework and PostgreSQL database(both configuration/integration is fine, means I can see on console that it's driver is downloaded with the above settings), the above code is working through Play framework only(my application is working on AngularJS+CoffeeScript+Play Framework).Now I need to store json object(shown in above code) in PostgreSQL using Play Framework or with any ? I don't know that how to do this ? Please help me !! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a controller that is receiving the request, or do you only have the client-side code written?

Comment: I have only client-side code written only. I don't have any controller side code to receive the requests.

Comment: The question seems to be "how do I write a Play application", so I suggest you work through the tutorial - https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Home

Comment: I mean I have some controller classes which belong to some other requirements, but I don't have any code regarding my current requirement in the controller classes, I can define in routes file: POST /json  @controllers.Application.jsonData, but what is actual code that I need to write in my Application Controller ? I am not sure ? so from this I hope I need to connect to my database to send json data hopefully, but I dont know how to do here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100660/discussion-between-steve-chaloner-and-dhana).